# How to sort sub-items in a list by ascending order to display them in a tuples

Tags: python, list, sorting, lambda, tuples

Lets say I have **exactly** this list : ["('Jeff', 8)", "('Louis', 9)","('Deandre', 5)"]
I want to be able to display in the console **exactly** this :

('Deandre',5)

('Jeff',8)

('Louis',9)

So that the 2nd element of the tuples are in ascending order (5,8,9...)

I tried with something like this :

sorted(mylist, key=lambda x: x[1])

But nothing...

Answer (score 1):

First parse the strings to tuples using `ast.literal_eval`, then sort:

```py
from ast import literal_eval

lst = ["('Jeff', 8)", "('Louis', 9)", "('Deandre', 5)"]

out = sorted(map(literal_eval, lst), key=lambda x: x[1])
print(*out)
```

Prints:

```
('Deandre', 5) ('Jeff', 8) ('Louis', 9)
```